# Put a where clause around a stored procedure I cannot edit

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I do not have access to edit called `[usp_ItemsAndDescriptions]`.

This gives a result, and my call looks like this:

```
USE [eboghandel]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_ItemsAndDescriptions]
        @StartDate = N'2014-06-01',
        @EndDate = N'2014-06-19',
        @Top = 10000

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This stored procedure then gives a list of fields. One of the fields are called `PressDescription`.

Now I want to make a `WHERE` statement, so I could say:

```
SELECT * FROM MYSTOREDPROCEDURERESULT mys WHERE mys.PressDescription = '1'
```

What is the syntax to do this? I do not have access to edit the stored procedure unfortunately, even though that would be optimal.

Comment: Cant you create the stored procedure with the WHERE condition column as a Parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load return data from SP to temporary table and filter this table by WHERE clause:

Create temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
   ...
)
```

Insert data in table

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC usp_ItemsAndDescriptions 
@StartDate = N'2014-06-01',
@EndDate = N'2014-06-19',
@Top = 10000
```

Filter your data

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp mys WHERE mys.PressDescription = '1'
```

Also check this link - there a lot of methods to load data from SP [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure?rq=1)